# Find the port of the server the application is running in java

Tags: java, port

Hi I have an application running in tomcat,as well as Weblogic and Websphere
I need to determine which port the application is running and display on the UI
Is there any JAVA api to find that

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Which UI - the user's browser, something else?  Is the browser already talking to the application, or are you trying to implement something that will allow the user to find the application's URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is already accessed through that port, you can easily get it from `HttpServletRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by inkredibl the ServletRequest method [getServerPort](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getServerPort%28%29) provides this information:

*Returns the port number to which the request was sent. It is the value of the part after ":" in the Host  header value, if any, or the server port where the client connection was accepted on.*

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask a server from the outside for which ports are used by which application. (Ahh, you cam try, but it shouldn't tell). That's obviously a security feature (you could start a port scan, but I guess, that's not exactly what you want...or?)

So the only way out - the application needs to communicate its port number to outer space, either by a simple web page, where the actual port number is desplayed (human-machine-interface) or a separate webservice with a static port number, where a client can request the actual server properties (machine-machine-interface).

*(Note: I assumed, the 'UI' is a client application...)*